# C++ Declare instance variable in header and call constructor in source file

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, declaration, definition

I learn C++ at the moment and as far as I know instance variables should be declared in a Header file. An example header (.hpp) looks like:

```
class myClass {
private:
    int i;
    std::ifstream file;
    anotherClass aClassObj;
public:
    //methods
}
```

I would like to initialize the variables in my source file (.cpp). For int it's only:

```
i = 4;
```

How would I do it for instance variables? In Java it would be `variableName = new Classname(ConstructorParam1, ConstructorParam2);`

However this is not possible in C++ because `file = new ifstream("filename");` results in a type mismatch as `new <...>;` returns a pointer.
Should I do a `file.open("filename");` instead or something else?
How can I initialize my variable `aClassObj`, I would like to call a constructor with parameters?

Kind regards

Comment: The first place to start is a good book, or at least the differences between Java and C++.

Comment: In C++ is easier you wouldn't have to provide `new`. But you would have to define a user defined constructor, where you'd initialize your member variables.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you'll need to create constructor for you class (possibly multiple overloaded ones) as you would do in Java. Since C++ is based on values rather than pointers as Java (mostly; some fundamental types like integers are treated as values in Java), you normally don't need to use `new` in C++ unless you faff about with dynamic polymorphism. A constructor for your class could look, e.g., like this (obviously, it needs to be declared in the class definition of `myClass`):

```
myClass::myClass(int i, std::string const& name, AParam1 p1, AParam2 p2)
    : i(i)
    , file(name.c_str()) // if you use C++11 or later you can omit .c_str())
    , aClassObj(p1, p2) {
}
```

You didn't specify what kind of arguments the constructor of the class `anotherClass` takes. The code above assumes two arguments of type `AParam1` and `AParam2`. Most likely you don't need to get all parameters from constructor parameters but have values ready. For example, you might always want to initialize the `i` member with the value `0` in which case you wouldn't need a parameter and just use the constant.

The keyword you want to look-up in your C++ tutorial is *member initializer lists*: this is how members are initialized in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a constructor with parameters, you could initialize the instance with no parameters and then set the attributes of the object . For instance, in the header file;

```
#include "anotherClass.h"    
class Myclass{
      public:
        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
        int a;
        int b;
        anotherClass aClassObj;
      };
```

then in the constructor of MyClass.cpp file;

```
MyClass::MyClass(){
   aClassObj.setParams(a, b);
}
```

Meanwhile, your "anotherClass" has this format in the header;

```
class anotherClass{
   public:
      anotherClass();
      ~anotherClass();
      int x;
      int y;
      void setParams(int a, int b);
};
```

and the .cpp file has this constructor and the set method;

```
anotherClass::anotherClass(){
}
void anotherClass::setParams(int a, int b){
    x = a;
    y = b;
}
```